# select tag event when mouse pass on option / select option with onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far i have created  a simple select tag (which work) which change an image when the option is changed (which mean I have to click to make the change and thus to change the picture):

```
<form  method="post" action="">
<select name="selectImageName3" id="selectImage3"  onchange="change3()" >                  
     <option value="opt1">Image1</option>
     <option value="opt2">Image2</option>
     <option value="opt3">Image3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

However I want that my image changes when the mouse pass on the option and according to the option. This means that when the mouse pass on an option (no click) then:
- the associated option value has to be recorded (to be used on my js function change3)
- the function change3() has to be activated.

I assume this is done generally using onmouseover but as I have understand it don t work for select tag.

Is anyone know/have a way to handle this? For instance is select2 will solve the problem? I don't specially focus on html, javascript, css or jquery is fine to me as long as i can handle my issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this. You add mouseover function to the select tag e.g.

```
$(document).ready( 

     function (event) {
        $('select').mouseover(function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
       //do something with the target
     });

});
```

where $(target).val() gives the value of the option you hovered on.